# Django fails to use the django version in virutalenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I am using django 1.11 on Ubuntu but the non-virtual python has 1.6. There are other apps using 1.6. When I run my application through apache mod_wsgi, it uses 1.6 instead of 1.11 and I get stack trace.

**Apache conf:**

```
    WSGIPythonPath /home/wondi/envs/my_app
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName server.com
        ServerAdmin admin@server.com

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

        WSGIDaemonProcess server.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
        WSGIProcessGroup server.com
        WSGIPassAuthorization On
        WSGIScriptAlias /my_app /home/wondi/envs/my_app/my_app/wsgi.py

        <Directory "/home/wondi/envs/my_app/my_app/">
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Order deny,allow
                Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/wondi/envs/my_app/app/static/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None  
            Require all granted
            IndexOptions FancyIndexing
        </Directory>

    ...
    </VirtualHost>
```

**my_app\wsgi.py:**

```
    import os
    import sys
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

    import site

    env_path = '/home/wondi/envs/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
    # we add currently directory to path and change to it
    working_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    os.chdir(working_dir)
    sys.path = [working_dir] + sys.path

    # Append paths
    site.addsitedir(env_path)

    sys.path.append('/home/wondi/envs/')
    sys.path.append('/home/wondi/envs/my_app/')

    os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "my_app.settings"

    activate_this = "/home/wondi/envs/bin/activate_this.py"
    execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

    application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**Stack trace:**

```
    Django Version: 1.6.1
    Python Version: 2.7.6
    Installed Applications:
    ['django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.gis',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'rest_framework',
     'rest_framework_gis',
     'corsheaders',
     'my_app']
    Installed Middleware:
    ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


    Traceback:
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      99.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
      337.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
      365.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
      360.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
      40.         __import__(name)
    File "/home/wondi/envs/my_app/my_app/urls.py" in <module>
      19. from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
    File "/home/wondi/envs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/urlpatterns.py" in <module>
      5. from rest_framework.compat import RegexURLResolver, include
    File "/home/wondi/envs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/compat.py" in <module>
      12. from django.apps import apps

    Exception Type: ImportError at /
    Exception Value: No module named apps
```

Is there anything that I missed or that can be done to fix the issue?

Comment: I would say you should be activating virtualenv before modifying sys.path or importing anything. The minute you imported django.core.wsgi you imported django not from your virtualenv. When you run activate (shouldn't it be a shell script?) you modify your env variables, overriding the variables you've set. So try reordering your wsgi.py (literally in reverse).

Comment: I totally get it. It is exactly what you said. It is working now. Could you post it as answer?

Comment: Read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html which shows preferred way of setting up virtual environments with mod_wsgi.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have read that. I will use it when I have control of a server.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have need to edit wsgi.py for activate virtualenv.
You need to run configure apache configuration in correct way.
Use `WSGIDaemonProcess` for mention project path virtualenv path that will run django project from virtuaenv.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/home/sammy/myproject/myprojectenv python-path=/home/sammy/myproject
```

As explained in:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Also follow this tutorial for apache with django https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04